# Facilitating PayPal Payment Gateway transactions between users on a site

Tags: paypal, django-rest-framework, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I am making a website in which users of a website can pay each other on-site like a fiver, Upwork and other platforms.

I want to use the PayPal payment gateway for this purpose. And using Django-rest-framework at the backend.

Are there any tutorials or documentation you guys can refer me to?

here is code when I try to send request to Paypal using payee method.

```
class PaymentP2P(APIView):
permission_classes = ()
# authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)

def post(self,request):
    email_request=request.data['payee']
    price_to_pay = str(request.data['price'])
    payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment(self.build_request_body(email_request,price_to_pay))
    print(payment)
    if payment.create():
        print("Payment created successfully")
    else:
        print(payment.error)
    return Response({'paymentID':payment.id},status=200)


@staticmethod
def build_request_body(email_user="payee@email.com",price="220.00"):
    """Method to create body with a custom PAYEE (receiver)"""
    return \
        {
        "intent": "AUTHORIZE",           
        "purchase_units": [
            {
             "amount": {
                "total": price,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "payee": {
                "email_address": "sb-loe4o1374588@personal.example.com"
            },
            },
        ]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For one user to pay another user's email, you can use [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/) with a `payee` variable: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Here are some front-end demo patterns of the basic checkout:

- One that calls endpoints on your server to set up and capture
  transactions:
  https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server
- One that
  does not do that, and only uses client-side js:
  https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: Hi hope you are doing fine. I have tried to pay to user using paypalrestsdk payee method but it returns null instead of tokenId of payee. Is there anything you can help me with. I am also sharing code for that here.

Comment: PayPal API endpoints do not return null. You will need to debug your API call.

Comment: I have added the code above can you tell me what's the issue, I will be thankfull